# Which policy actions must be permitted to upload a file to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When using the JS SDK to upload to an s3 bucket, the following policy works:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but the more granular and secure

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

does not.  Is there some additional action permission necessary to upload an object?

Comment: This policy should be enough. What API call are you trying? Maybe you're inadvertently trying a s3:ListBucket (or any other API call). That would explain your error.

Comment: @Simon-Pierre I am using the aws-sdk's S3.upload() function: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/23ae71e7da812d5603a8f4cc6126d6c6871cd6b4/lib/services/s3.js#L819

Comment: the aws-sdk's S3.upload() function uses multipart upload. You're probably missing the `s3:ListMultipartUploadParts` action

Comment: For all possible actions you can specify, refer to this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html

Comment: @Simon-Pierre still no luck after adding `s3:ListMultipartUploadParts` : "Access Denied." Is there some way to tell which permissions AWS wanted, but did not see?

Comment: You can use the policy simulator (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your policy grants permissions to objects, not the bucket. This should work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo/"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice the difference between the bucket (`arn:aws:s3:::foo/`) and objects (`arn:aws:s3:::foo/*`).